# Is there a way to save old logs as archived and then delete the archived file?

Tags: java, logging, gzip, logback

I have a project which saves logs of all the other services. It is configured in such a way that it keeps only 7 days logs and deletes older logs every day.

But I want to know if there is a configuration through which I can save the logs older then 7 days into .gz format into new folder and then then delete those 7 days older logs. If I want to need to look into any older issue then I can just unzip the old logs.

Currently my configuration is like this ->

```xml
<appender name="FILE-ERROR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>%highlight([%level]) - [%date] - [%logger] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!--  rollover daily  -->
        <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/app-error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
        <!-- output messages of exact level only  -->
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

Logback do not have any out of the box functionality to create zip from achieved log folder. However you shell script (Unix) or batch script (Windows) and schedule it to run as per needed timeline. You will easily find sample shell/batch scripts which you can modify.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no policy in log rotation in Java to zip the old files, but you can do it using chron-tab schedule if in Unix based OS.

Just skip writing specifying the  (TimeBasedRollingPolicy) to delete the files after 7 days, then you should just not specify 7 in your configuration.

You should just leave the  out; it's optional and if it's not there, then archived log files are not deleted.

Then write a crontab that will gunzip or zip the files periodically(once in a day in your case).

I hope it helps.